# query to get equal number of rows per category + sub category

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

This is how my SQL table structure looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE TempCategory
(
    Id BIGINT,
    Name VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE TempSubCategory
(
    Id BIGINT,
    CategoryId BIGINT,
    Name VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE TempProduct
(
    Id BIGINT,
    SubCategoryId BIGINT,
    Name VARCHAR(100)
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2606fd/4

I am writing a SSRS report that displays Category as x axis, Sub Category as y axis and Products as data. Each Category will have its own Sub Categories so i am displaying Sub Categories in the column group for each row group.

SSRS report does not draw the cells for the rows for which it does not get the values. So my report ends up looking like this:

[image: ssrs report]

This is how my current query looks like:

```
SELECT  TempCategory.Id, 'MainCategoryId',
        TempCategory.Name 'CategoryName',
        TempSubCategory.id 'SubCategoryId',
        TempSubCategory.Name 'SubCategory',
        TempProduct.Id 'ProductId',
        TempProduct.Name 'ProductName'
          FROM TempCategory
    INNER JOIN TempSubCategory
        ON TempCategory.Id = TempSubCategory.CategoryId
    INNER JOIN TempProduct
        ON TempSubCategory.Id = TempProduct.SubCategoryId
```

What i am looking to do is modify the query in such a way that it always returns the same number of rows per sub category group so that i have nulls or 0 in the rows for which it does have the data.

For example: Category 1 has 3 sub categories and the max number of products are in Sub Category 1 so i want the query to return 5 (max number of products for sub category 1)
rows for each sub category which has Main Category 1.

For Category 2, it will return 2 rows per Sub Category as max number of products are with Sub Category 2.

Is it possible to do it in SQL or is there some other way to do it in SSRS report?

*--Update--*

This is a table with ProductName row group

[image: Table]

This is matrix with SubCategory column group

[image: Matrix]

This is a table with Product Name row group

[image: Table]

Comment: Are you able to supply a screenshot of your report in the Designer mode? Just to get an idea of the groupings involved in the tablix itself and how everything fits together.

Comment: Also, in you actual data, is there any relationship between products like say `Cat1SubCat1Product1` and `Cat1SubCat1Product1` - they are in the same row, but could the products in a column be in any order, and do they have anything in common with neighboring columns?

Comment: @IanPreston : I have updated the question with design mode screen shots. No, There is no relation between two products. They are children of SubCategory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, here's one (roundabout) way of doing it:

```
with numbers as -- create lazy numbers table; feel free to replace with a proper one
(
  select distinct number
  from master..spt_values
  where number between 1 and 100
)
, rowCounts as
(
  select Category = tc.Name
    , SubCategory = tsc.Name
    , SubCategoryId = tsc.Id
    , MaxSubCatRows = count(1)
  from TempCategory tc
    inner join TempSubCategory tsc on tc.Id = tsc.CategoryId
    inner join TempProduct p on tsc.Id = p.SubCategoryId
  group by tc.Name
    , tsc.Name
    , tsc.Id
)
, maxRowCountPerGroup as
(
  select Category
    , MaxSubCatRows = max(MaxSubCatRows)
  from rowCounts
  group by Category
)
, allCats as
(
  select rc.Category
    , rc.SubCategory
    , rc.SubCategoryId
    , n.number
  from rowCounts rc
    inner join maxRowCountPerGroup mr on rc.Category = mr.Category
    cross apply (select number
                 from numbers
                 where number between 1 and mr.MaxSubCatRows) n
)
, orderedProducts as
(
  select *
    , productRowNumber = row_number() over (partition by SubCategoryId
                                            order by Id)
  from TempProduct
)
select c.Category
  , c.SubCategory
  , Product = p.Name
from allCats c
  left join orderedProducts p on c.subCategoryId = p.subCategoryId
    and c.number = p.productRowNumber
order by c.Category
  , c.SubCategory
  , case when p.Name is null then 1 else 0 end -- nulls last
  , p.Name
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2606fd/29).

So... What this is doing is:

- Get row counts for each category/subcategory combo
- Get max of these row counts per group
- Use numbers table to create `n` placeholder rows for each
  category/subcategory combo, where `n` is the max for the category
  from above
- Assign row numbers for each product in a subcategory
- Left join our category placeholder rows to our ordered products

Now we have the required number of rows, including the required `NULL` rows to pad out the SSRS report.

All that is left is to apply this to the report Dataset; sit back and admire the extra rows that have appeared.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your time and effort for putting this together.